# SuspiciousRemoteServerError what I can do?

Tags: exchange, email-server

from some time i have a problem with send e-mails. I have a Exchange 2013 with SP2, newest CU. When I try to send e-mail with attachment I get a error:
I have a kaspersky security 8.0.

SMTPSEND.SuspiciousRemoteServerError; remote server disconnected abruptly; retry will be delayed};{FQDN=};

What i've tried:

- Update Exchange to SP2 and newest CU21
- Update Kaspersky to newest update
- Check SPF with mxtools
- Add new network interface to VM - Exchange machine is a VM @ Windows 2012
- We arent on any spam lists
- Create new send connector: send e-mail by MX record associated with recipient domain, not by any smart host.
- We have a Cisco Router, but not Firewall like ASA - no fixup protocol smtp 25 is not working, There arent any Firewall
- In send connectere I apply logging but there isnt any suspisious in logs.

I dont have any more idea what I can do. Ive tried SMTPDiag but everything looks fine.

Help me please...

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been resolved. It was problem with our network. we've reduced bandwidth of VM NIC and problem has disappeared.

Answer (score -1):

Hope the following thread helps:
451 4.4.0 SMTPSEND.SuspiciousRemoteServerError; remote server disconnected abruptly
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/02bf81fb-e434-44d1-859c-b329793a1e13/451-440-smtpsendsuspiciousremoteservererror-remote-server-disconnected-abruptly?forum=Exch2016MFSM

Comment: Just linking to an external site is not something which is seen as helpful on StackExchange.